# python update Query with subtracting columns

Tags: python, pyodbc

I trying to run sql query in python to update quantity but i am getting error .

```
cur.execute(
  "UPDATE Products SET Price =? , Quantity =? , RackLocation =? WHERE ID =?",
   [self.new_price.get(), self.new_quantity.get(), self.new_racklocation.get(), self.id]
)
```

i am getting this error:

```
[int(self.new_quantity.get()) ,  int(self.id)])    
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]
[SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '='. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] 
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be 
prepared. (8180)")
```

Comment: What are your get methods returning if you simply print them to console?

Comment: [Edit] your Question and explain the meaning of *"subtracting columns"*?

Comment: hi thanks for your reply  actually my query was wrong . I changed my query to this it works .

Comment: cur.execute("UPDATE Products SET  Quantity =  Quantity - 1   WHERE ID=?",
                    [self.id])

Answer (score 0):

I was doing wrong . Query should look like this

cur.execute("UPDATE Products SET  Quantity =  Quantity - 1   WHERE ID=?",
                    [self.id])